# select query for a specific month based on some conditions

Tags: mysql, date

I am pretty new to mysql and need your help. i need to query the following and i have a problem with the last part of the query where it says "within the month prior to the eNews deployment." I looked into the Date functions like date_sub but i could not figure it out.
I have tried Select IDs from table where country = 'CA' and miles between 30000 and 39000. 
I could not do the last part of the query.

"Canadian members who reached a miles balance of 30,000 to 39,999 within the month prior to the eNews deployment."

sorry if it is very basic.
thanks for the help

Comment: show your table definitions with sample dataset and the end result dateset that you need from query